# How do I add an amount field to stripe.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am trying to modify [Stripe's quickstart form](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart) by adding an amount field so that customers can enter the amount they'd like to be charged. I'd like it to appear before the Card Number field, but it won't render. I am trying to clone the expiry field (or any field for that matter) and insert it before the card number:

```
$(".CardField-expiry").clone().insertBefore(".CardField-number");
```

The new field doesn't show but I notice in the DOM there is now an iframe element being created.

[My Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/9jytz58b/1/) but I feel like this is doing things the hard way and maybe there's a built-in way to do it with stripe.js I am missing??

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation on the paymentRequest call](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-payment-request)? there you can set the amount based on another element.

Comment: Hi there, the stripe hosted form are hosted by Stripe and rendered within an `iframe` which you will not be able to modify through normal javascript DOM modifications. You could create a separate input outside the iframe as normal inptu field though.

Comment: @Máté the amount is variable and set by the user. Unless I'm misunderstanding that wouldn't work???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As wsw mentioned, the form created by Stripe is hosted in an iframe so you won't be able to access it directly. This is to ensure PCI compliance on your webpage.

You could look into using [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/variable-amount-checkout#form) instead, which will allow you to have a variable amount field in your form.